# Avoid loading new page after the print and next page should print from the remaining portion of last printed page - dot matrix printer

Tags: javascript, css, printing, mpmediaquery

I am printing a page using a dot matrix printer by using javascript print() method and by use of @media print methods in css.

My print.css as follows:

```
@media print {
    html, body { 
        font-family: 'Arial', 'Helvetica',sans-serif;
        font-size: 15pt;
        margin : 0px;
    }
}
@page {
      size: 22cm 10cm;
      margin : 0px;
    }
```

My printable detail is very small suppose two lines of data. But after printing 
the printer skips the current printed page and feeding another page.

**I want to avoid feeding next page and the next print should happen from the same page which is printed last.**

I have tried:

```
@media print {
    page-break-after: avoid;
}
```

But not working at all.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `*` selector css:

```
@media print {
  * { 
    page-break-before: avoid;
    page-break-after: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try defining a page size something like

```
@page {
      size: 21.59cm 13.97cm;
}
```

should work